# Blueimp [Error TypeError: '0' is null or not an object] error

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I have problem with this. ı get this error when click start.

I am reading and updating my code since morning, still ı couldnt solve it.

my problem:

I installed the demo and everything worked fine. Edited the index.html page to use a subfolder as there were name clashes and everything appeared to work but I get the above error in IE8. FF & Chrome work fine with the original demo and the subfolder versions.

A page refresh shows that the files uploaded correctly as they are now available for download.

I've tried this on the original version and the jQuery UI version and both exhibit the same problem.

Please can anyone shed any light on this?
I have a [thread](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/1030) also at Github, with a little more information.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst trying to get the same project to work on my server, I had similar issues.
Here are a few tips:

- Make sure the *application pool* of your web-application has rights to write to the upload directory.
- If you are using asp.net, make sure you are not running a .net 4 application under a .net 3.5 application in iis.
- If you are using asp.net, make sure you have set the storage directory correctly in your web.config.
- Make sure you are not testing an upload of a file that doesn't match your file-filter. (that is, if your file-filter limits you to .jpg, make sure you aren't testing with a .txt file)